# @PathParam doesn't get me the path variable

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I've got a POST Method (which takes some JSON data). I also want to access a Path Parameter "id" for my processing. However when I use the "@PathParam" I get the JSON body which I had passed to the request. Below is my code :

```
@Path("/products")
public class PurchaseService {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("{id}/purchase")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String doPurchaseForUser(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        String result = null;
        System.out.println("Product : " + id);
        return id;
    }
}
```

If I pass in the POST body as - {"user_id":123} , the id variable in the code above holds this value and not the id value from the URI. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the actual URI that you're posting to when you test?

Comment: This is the URI - http://localhost:8080/ShoppingSocieties/Shopping/products/1/purchase with POST body - {"user_id":123}

Comment: @PathParam would deal with localhost:8080/ShoppingSocieties/Shopping/products/123/purchase

Answer (score 3):

You're importing the wrong `@PathParam`. It should be `javax.ws.rs.PathParam`. You're probably importing the websocket one (which is a common mistake when you have the javaee-api dependency).

Answer (score 1):

When you annotate your method with `@Consumes ("application/json")` it means that you are telling your web service : this method is waiting for an object in json format as a parameter. This is why your String id is taking the json content.

```
@Path("/products")
```

public class PurchaseService {

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/purchase")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String doPurchaseForUser(@QueryParam("id") String id,JsonObject jsonContent) {
    String result = null;
    System.out.println("Product : " + id);
    return id;
}
```

}

Your call url will look like this 
`localhost:8080/ShoppingSocieties/Shopping/products/purchase?id=1`

Comment: No need to change PathParam to QueryParam - the magic is done by adding the JsonObject parameter.